# mysql_fetch_array dropping first entry

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display a list of links based upon mysql output. The code works except that it drops the first record. I know it is because of the duplicate [ #row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3) ] entries but if i remove one the code fails. Can anyone suggest a fix?

Thanks

```
<?php
 $sql3 = "SELECT `Record_ID`, `Name` FROM `rides` WHERE `Rating` = 3";
 $result3=mysql_query($sql3)or die(mysql_error());
 //var_dump ($result3);
 $num = mysql_num_rows($result3);
 while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
      {
   echo "<table>";
   for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++){
       $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
   //var_dump($row3);
        $ridesid = $row3[0];
       $rides = $row3[1];
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<a href='attraction_page.php?rideID=". urlencode($ridesid) ."'>$rides</a>";
   echo "<br />";
       echo "</tr>";
 }

    echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you calling `mysql_fetch_array` twice?  And why do they both set the same variable (`$row3`)?

Comment: Why are you looping through it twice? There's your issue right there. One loop containing `mysql_fetch_array()` is all you need.

Comment: Thank you.... I didn't even see the double loop.

Comment: You better start using `mysqli` or `PDO`, as `mysql_*` family of functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have fetch same thing twice!
 Try this:

```
 <?php
     $sql3 = "SELECT `Record_ID`, `Name` FROM `rides` WHERE `Rating` = 3";
     $result3=mysql_query($sql3)or die(mysql_error());
     //var_dump ($result3);
     $num = mysql_num_rows($result3);
      echo "<table>";
     while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
          {

           $ridesid = $row3[0];
           $rides = $row3[1];
           echo "<tr>";
           echo "<a href='attraction_page.php?rideID=". urlencode($ridesid) ."'>$rides</a>";
           echo "<br />";
            echo "</tr>";
         }

        echo '</table>';

    ?>
```

Comment: @GMORROW : did you try this?

Comment: I deleted the WHILE loop and left the FOR loop in place

Comment: @GMORROW: I think you should accept an answer. if you have get solution from here :)

Comment: Still using dem deprecated functions tho

Comment: @Strawberry: good point. We can suggest him to use mysqli or pdo. But i have posted the solution of his problem with his existing code :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I plan on upgrading the code. Just trying to get it working first.

Answer (score 0):

Call mysql_fetch_array() only once...